# How do I log onto a WiFi network with username and password on Windows 10?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-10

I am trying to log onto my school's wireless network with a Windows 10 OS. Previously on Win8 there was an option to use certain credentials:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/R3mHUqU.jpg]

Now this option no longer seems available!

How do I change the wireless networks setting to enable a username and password?

Comment: How was the wireless network profile added to the computer when it was running Windows 8? Is it being added the same way now that you're on Windows 10?

Comment: @Twisty It was in the pop out that came from the right side. Like the Charms bar.

Comment: What happens when you attempt to connect? Do you get an error?